# creating a asterixis rectangle with a center

Tags: python

I have code for  a hollow box but need help putting a 1x1 asterix in the exact center

```
width = int(input('Enter your width'))
height = int(input('Enter your height'))
for i in range(1, height + 1):
   for j in range(1, height + 1):
       if (i == 1 or i == height or j == 1 or j == height):
           print("*", end="")
       else:
           print(" ", end="")
   print()
```

Comment: What if it is an uneven, like a 4X4, what would be the center then

Comment: if that happens then the center will not print

Comment: You are not using `width` at all

Comment: And do u need a boundary? @alex

Comment: I need  boundary input, so like a length and width. @SiddharthAgrawal

Comment: I mean like a boundary to denote the box. You of course need the width and height input

Comment: You may think about [accepting an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to reward those how helped you, or at least comment to explain what's missing ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is the code without a boundary. I am adding the code with the boundary in a minute. The code is pretty straightforward but let me know if you do not understand something

```
width = int(input('Enter your width'))
height = int(input('Enter your height'))


if (width%2==1 and height%2==1):
 centerW = round(width/2)
 centerH = round(height/2)
 h = 1
 while h<centerH:
  print()
  h+=1

 w = 1
 while w<centerW:
  print(" ",end="")
  w+=1
 print("*")  

 h = 1
 while h<centerH:
  print()
  h+=1

 print()
 print("Finished")  
else:
  print("The input was even")
```

Answer (score 0):

You may add a `if` case for when

- both dimension are odd
- you are at middle for `height` and `width`

```
from math import ceil

def show(height, width):
    both_even = height % 2 == 1 and width % 2 == 1
    for i in range(1, height + 1):
        for j in range(1, width + 1):
            if i == 1 or i == height or j == 1 or j == width:
                print("*", end="")
            elif both_even and ceil(height / 2) == i and ceil(width / 2) == j:
                print("*", end="")
            else:
                print(" ", end="")
        print()
```

Here are 2 examples

```
*********
*       *
*       *
*   *   *
*       *
*       *
*********
--------------------
***********
*         *
*    *    *
*         *
***********
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach with minimal modifications to your code:

```py
width = int(input('Enter your width'))
height = int(input('Enter your height'))

center = ((width+1)/2, (height+1)/2)

for i in range(1, width + 1):
   for j in range(1, height + 1):
       if i == 1 or i == width or j == 1 or j == height or ((i,j) == center and width%2 != 0 and height%2 != 0):
           print("*", end="")
       else:
           print(" ", end="")
   print()
```

**Explanation:**

1. get centre coordinates using by adding **1** and dividing by **2**
2. save them as a `tuple`
3. add 3 conditions to your `if` check:

   - check if a current coordinates are equal to values in `centre`
   - check if both width and height are odd
4. print `*` if conditions in 3 are passed